# How to know current focus is an input field in Linux?

Tags: linux, textfield, xlib, input-field

I am using Linux system on a Pad, and I want to know whether current focus is an input field so that I can pop up a soft-keyboard. 
Is there any way to know this event in X?

Answer (score 0):

At X level this is not possible, you need to integrate at UI toolkit level ( Gtk+, Qt etc )

Comment: Hi, I'm not familiar with GTK+ or Qt, can you share with me what I should use in GTK+ to implement this?

Comment: Me neither, but I know a bit about low level X11 protocol